# Android layout Height and width

Tags: android, xml, layout

I use `match_parent` for height,but I don't want to use `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` for width. I want to set height as same as width. How can I do that in `layout.xml`?

Comment: Am not sure how you do that, but the best way to try something like this would be to use the `Design` pane to play around with it and see what works.

Comment: Don't think you can do this in xml. Your best bet will be to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question largely depends on whether you are in portrait or landscape.

If you are trying to make a layout width to match the height in portrait, then your layout will be going off screen, which does not seem possible in xml. And vice-versa, matching the height to the width in landscape would make the layout go offscreen as well.

If you are trying to make a square layout the same dimension as the smallest dimension of the screen, then a round about way to do that in xml is to make a shape drawable that is square, transparent and larger than your screen size. Then set the drawable to be an imageview inside a relativelayout and set your width and heights to the proper settings (match_parent or wrap_content). Then add views to the relativelayout as needed and reference them to the parent and not the image, making the new views reside "on top" of the imageview.

In portrait, the following relativelayout is square:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/square_draw" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In landscape, the following relativelayout is square:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/white"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" >

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:src="@drawable/square_draw" />

       </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Also, make sure that adjustViewBounds is set to true.  For some reason, this solution does not allow the image to grow larger than the screen size and it also uses more resources due to the overdraw.